# jQuery Datatables Handle Null sub objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables but encountering issues when my JSON sub object is `null`. My JSON has a nested object `address` which can be `null`, thus `address.streetAddress1` below returns an error/warning.

> DataTables warning: table id=directory-table - Requested unknown parameter 'address.streetAddress1' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Is there a way to handle `null` values so it is just a blank string?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#directory-table').dataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 100 ],
        "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
        "ajax": {
            "url": "directory.json",
            "dataSrc" : ""
        },
        scrollX:true,
        "columns": [
            {"data" : "fileId"},
            {"data" : "fileName"},
            {"data" : "institutionId"},
            {"data" : "id"},
            {"data" : "firstName"},
            {"data" : "middleName"},
            {"data" : "lastName"},
            {"data" : "prefix"},
            {"data" : "suffix"},
            {"data" : "preferredName"},
            {"data" : "gender"},
            {"data" : "deleteFlag"},
            {"data" : "campusId"},
            {"data" : "buildingId"},
            {"data" : "primaryEmail"},
            {"data" : "secondaryEmail"},
            {"data" : "primaryPhone"},
            {"data" : "secondaryPhone"},
            {"data" : "address.streetAddress1"},
            {"data" : "address.city"},
            {"data" : "address.state"},
            {"data" : "address.zipCode"},
            {"data" : "orcid"},
            {"data" : "trResearcherId"},
            {"data" : "status.name"},
            {"data" : "roomNumber"},
            {"data" : "createdAt"},
            {"data" : "updatedAt"}
        ]
    } );
} );
```

This record has `null` for `address`:

```
{"fileId":2,"fileName":"9999_DIRECTORY.csv","institutionId":1,"id":"EVER1003","firstName":"George","lastName":"Clooney","middleName":null,"prefix":null,"suffix":null,"preferredName":null,"gender":"M","deleteFlag":"N","campusId":null,"primaryEmail":"cclooney","secondaryEmail":null,"primaryPhone":null,"secondaryPhone":null,"address":null,"buildingId":null,"orcid":null,"trResearcherId":null,"status":{"id":0,"name":"Processed"},"tags":null,"roomNumber":null,"createdAt":"2015-07-22 15:41 PM GMT","updatedAt":"2015-07-22 15:41 PM GMT"}
```

This record has an `address`:

```
{"fileId":2,"fileName":"9999_DIRECTORY.csv","institutionId":1,"id":"EVER1013","firstName":"Monica","lastName":"Galler","middleName":null,"prefix":null,"suffix":null,"preferredName":null,"gender":"F","deleteFlag":"N","campusId":"CAMP1000","primaryEmail":"monica@gmail.com","secondaryEmail":null,"primaryPhone":null,"secondaryPhone":null,"address":{"id":0,"streetAddress1":"123 Fake Street","streetAddress2":null,"city":"Cincinnati","state":"OH","stateId":0,"zipCode":"32444"},"buildingId":null,"orcid":null,"trResearcherId":null,"status":{"id":0,"name":"Processed"},"tags":null,"roomNumber":null,"createdAt":"2015-07-23 14:31 PM GMT","updatedAt":"2015-07-24 18:18 PM GMT"}
```

Comment: Can you please show the portion of JSON that has NULL value? What version of DataTables are you using?

Comment: I added the sample JSON. I am using version 1.10.7.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`columns.defaultContent`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent) option.

According to the [manual](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent):

> Additionally, this option can be useful when loading JSON data, as the value set here will be used if the cell value from the JSON is found to be `null` (for example, you might set a default string of "Not available.").

For example:

```
        {"data" : "address.streetAddress1", "defaultContent": ""},
        {"data" : "address.city", "defaultContent": ""},
        {"data" : "address.state", "defaultContent": ""},
        {"data" : "address.zipCode", "defaultContent": ""},
```

Answer (score 1):

Using aoColumns you can specify a mRender parameter function call to check if the value in question is null. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#directory-table').dataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 100 ],
    "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
    "ajax": {
        "url": "directory.json",
        "dataSrc" : ""
    },
    scrollX:true,
    "aoColumns": [
        {"mData" : "fileId",
         "mRender": function( data, type, full) {
           if( data !== null ){
             return data;
           }
           else{
             return "";
           }
         },
         //More column definitions
```

http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns